# QGIS2threejs' display hugely miscalculated

Tags: dem, display, qgis2threejs

In QGIS, when I display a digital elevation model (DEM) using the add-on QGIS2threejs, I get this:

[image]

I discovered, though, I get THIS when I change the Scene Settings > Z Exaggeration from 1.0 to 0.0001 :

[image]

An even smaller number in Z Exaggeration gets me closer to reality.

Does anyone know why QGISthreejs is making such huge miscalculations?  A  1.0  Z Exaggeration SHOULD display the real-life elevations.

Comment: It only *should* if the units are the same in X, Y, and Z. If your X and Y were in degrees, while Z was in meters, well, you'd need an 1.0e-5 exaggeration to knock it down to something workable.